# Error while if(empty($_POST) === false) being called

Tags: php

I have two forms that are being submitted depending on the conditions.

I used

```
if(empty($_POST) === false)
```

to save data after an edit. But for the first time I encountered this situation which causes and error.

What do I need to do so that I can accommodate two forms on a page.???

Comment: What situation and what error?

Comment: What is the exact error message and what line of source code does it occur on?

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a hidden field in each of your forms...

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="edit" />
```

in the other form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="new" />
```

Then check `$_POST`for those specific values:

```
if (isset($_POST['do'])) {

    // a form was posted

    if ($_POST['do']=='edit') {

        // do sth with form 'edit'

    elseif ($_POST['do']=='new') {

        // do sth with form 'new'

    } // if $_P
} // if isset
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `REQUESTED_METHOD` because `form` could be set and be empty.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk edit: changed name of field to `do`- does your comment still apply?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) approach to this problem. You can check whatever the request method is `POST` (new) or `PUT` (edit) and deal with that.

For example if you have two forms, one for edit and one for creating items, you set the method to one of them with:

```
<form method="PUT" ...>
<form method="POST"...>
```

and retrieve the method via:

```
$_SERVER['REQUESTED_METHOD'];
```

therefore dividing them.